# PHP Check if in array an specific value is true

Tags: php, object

Can someone help me out.

I'm looking for an solution how to check if in $testArray there is an array with ['value']['content'] == 1

I have tried:

```
$bool = in_array('1', array_column($testArray, 'content'));
var_dump($bool);
```

But than I get an return FALSE, but if you take a look at the testArray below you see the first array has ['value']['content'] => '1';

```
<?php

        $testArray = array(
            array(
                'id' => '414-b9108bbe-66e3-4c1e-8a51-03b7b8a0d17c',
                'position' => 0,
                'type' => 'original',
                'value' => array
                    (
                        'comment' => '',
                        'content' => '1',
                        'info' => '',
                        'insight' => '',
                        'label' => '',
                        'report' => '',
                    )

            ),
            array(
                'id' => '414-b9108bbe-66e3-4c1e-8a51-03b7b8a0d18c',
                'position' => 0,
                'type' => 'original',
                'value' => array
                    (
                        'comment' => '',
                        'content' => '',
                        'info' => '',
                        'insight' => '',
                        'label' => '',
                        'report' => '',
                    )

            ),
        );

        echo '<pre>';
        $bool = array_search('content', array_column($testArray, 'value'));
        var_dump($bool);
        echo '</pre>';
```

I think its because of the value is an other Array because i do:

```
$bool = in_array('original', array_column($testArray, 'type'));
```

Output: true.

Comment: `&& $block['answer'][$which] === 1` ?

Comment: I fail to see a connection between `$block['answer']` and those arrays, sorry.

Comment: Why does your code check for `answer` within the array, but the examples you list don't mention it? Are you passing in the _entire_ `$testArray1` or `$testArray2` as the input, or only a subset of the array?

Comment: Forgot the function, its a very long array and alot of checks. There are alot of diffrent arrays. My bad to place it in the question im sorry.. I cant check of && $block['answer']['$wich'] because there start the array so there you have the $key[0] and $key[1] and there value and there the content.. If you know what i mean.

Comment: Little bit more info the $testArray is the same as an example of $block['answer'][$wich] from the function..

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Anything more than that single approach? Why not loop over the array?

Comment: array_filter($testArray, function ($x) {return $x['value']['content']=== '1';});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. (Sorry for my bad english,hope you can understand)

```
// This is a two-dimensional array, you only need to do the array_column operation once more
var_dump(in_array('1', array_column(array_column($testArray, 'value'), 'content')));
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it

Answer (score 0):

Try as below simple you can find any value from your array

```html
function searcharray($value, $key, $array) {
    
   foreach ($array as $k => $val) {
       if ($val[$key] == $value) {
           foreach ($val as $k1 => $val1) {
               if ($val1[$key] == $value) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           return true;
       }else{
           foreach ($val as $k1 => $val1) {
               if ($val1[$key] == $value) {
                   return true;
               }
           }
           
       }
   }
   return false;
}

var_dump(searcharray('0','position',$testArray));`enter code here`
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it